# Como fazer com que as background tasks continuem rodando quando o app vai para background no Flutter Android?

Tags: android, flutter, background, notificação

Tenho um aplicativo para uma empresa (específico) que possui algumas tasks com a finalidade de contar tempo, marcar macros e gerar notificações (tipo ponto eletrônico).

Quando o aplicativo fica muito tempo em segundo plano, as vezes o android congela as tasks e o app não consegue gerar as notificações no momento em que deveria ocorrer.
Quando o app volta pro primeiro plano, td se corrige e as notificações são exibidas retroativamente.

Como contornar essa situação?

---

Achei uma solução viável!

Analisando o site https://dontkillmyapp.com/ reparei que muitos também passam por esse mesmo problema, além de ver algumas ideias de solução.
Após comparar as soluções para as diferentes fabricantes, vi que alguns apps que possuem essa notificação em segundo plano já tem essa configuração qnd são instalados.

Pesquisando como "forçar" esta configuração, cheguei na seguinte solução:

pubspec.yaml

```
  android_power_manager: ^0.1.6
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
```

Função:

```
void init() async {
    var status = await Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.status;
    print("status: $status");
    if (status.isGranted) {
      print(
          "isIgnoring: ${(await AndroidPowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations)}");
      if (!(await AndroidPowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations)) {
        AndroidPowerManager.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations();
      }
    } else {
      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
        Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations,
      ].request();
      print(
          "permission value: ${statuses[Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations]}");
      if (statuses[Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations].isGranted) {
        AndroidPowerManager.requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations();
      } else {
        exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
```

AppWidget.dart (main)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    init();

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    DataTransferService().initTimerTask();
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: Modular.navigatorKey,
      title: APP_NAME,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginPage(),
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/notification': (context) => NotificationPage(),
        '/alerts': (context) => AlertsPage(),
      },
      onGenerateRoute: Modular.generateRoute,
    );
  }
```

Com isso, ele pede a permissão (se precisar) e, se tiver permissão, já gera o popup para o usuário permitir que o app seja exceção na otimização de bateria.

Agora as notificações estão chegando certinho! =]

Comment: Tenho uma má notícia para você, o controle é arbitrário e depende das fabricantes. Cada uma implementa medidas que acabam matando os apps e impedindo sua execução em background. Então de uma olhada no site https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: Isso é algo que o sistema operacional define e controla, há a meu ver essas task devem ser orquestradas pelo seu backend, exemplo quando uma taks fosse defnida seu backend enviaria um push e ao abrir o aplicativo, suas taks syncronizam com o back novamente.

Comment: sim... estou fazendo isso... mas existem algumas situações em que eu preciso alertar o usuário para tomar alguma ação no app, msm nessas situações.